# Node.js: Consolidate.js + Jade is not rendering Jade correctly

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using Express@3.0.0rc2 + jade@0.2.3 + consolidate@0.5.0. When I render a page, the output is not as expected. Here's the jade:

index.jade

```
extends ../../layouts/default
block headIncludes
    link(href='/_widgets/search/index.css',rel='stylesheet')
block footerIncludes
    script(type='text/javascript',src='/_widgets/search/index.js')
    script(src='/views/site/home/js/index.js')

block content
    header(class='jumbotron masthead')
       div.inner
           h1 Pricing Page
//Search
div.row-fluid
    div(class='span12 centeredText',id='searchWidget')
div.row-fluid
    div.span12
div.row-fluid
    div.span12
div.row-fluid
    div.span12
```

Here's the output:

```
<extends>../../layouts/default</extends><block>headIncludes</block> link(href='/_widgets/search/index.css',rel='stylesheet') <block>footerIncludes</block>  script(type='text/javascript',src='/_widgets/search/index.js')  script(src='/views/site/home/js/index.js')   <block>content</block> header(class='jumbotron masthead')      div.inner           h1 Pricing Page     //Search    div.row-fluid       div(class='span12 centeredText',id='searchWidget')  div.row-fluid       div.span12  div.row-fluid       div.span12  div.row-fluid       div.span12
```

As you can see, rather than evaluating Extends as Jade always has, it now creates

```
<extends>../../layouts/default</extends>
```

same for the Blocks.

```
<block>headIncludes</block>
```

Here's how I'm setting the app up:

app.js

```
....
var app = express()
require('./settings').boot(app, config, passport)
```

settings.js

```
var express = require('express')
, RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express)
, url = require("url")
, cons = require('consolidate')

exports.boot = function(app, config, passport){
   bootApplication(app, config, passport)
}

 // App settings and middleware

 function bootApplication(app, config, passport) {

   app.set('showStackError', true)

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

   app.use(express.logger(':method :url :status'))

// set views path, template engine and default layout


 app.configure(function () {

 app.engine('jade', require('jade').renderFile)

 app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views')
 app.set('view engine', 'jade')
 app.set('view options', { layout: false })

// cookieParser should be above session
app.use(express.cookieParser())

// bodyParser should be above methodOverride
app.use(express.bodyParser())
app.use(express.methodOverride())

var redisURL = process.env.REDISTOGO_URL || config.redis
console.log(redisURL)
var redisUrl = url.parse(redisURL),
    redisAuth = redisUrl.auth.split(':');  
app.set('redisHost', redisUrl.hostname);
app.set('redisPort', redisUrl.port);
app.set('redisDb', redisAuth[0]);
app.set('redisPass', redisAuth[1]); 

app.use(express.session({
  secret: '......',
  cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 360000)}, //1 Hour
  store: new RedisStore({
        host: app.set('redisHost'),
        port: app.set('redisPort'),
        db: app.set('redisDb'),
        pass: app.set('redisPass')
    })
}))



app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(express.favicon())

require('./config/customMiddleware').boot(app)  

// routes should be at the last
app.use(app.router)

// assume "not found" in the error msgs
// is a 404. this is somewhat silly, but
// valid, you can do whatever you like, set
// properties, use instanceof etc.



app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  // treat as 404
  if (~err.message.indexOf('not found')) return next()

  // log it
  console.error(err.stack)

  // error page
  res.status(500).render('500')
})

// assume 404 since no middleware responded
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404).render('404', { url: req.originalUrl })
})

})

app.set('showStackError', false)

}
```

This seems really strange to me because Jade looks to be compiling a little bit, just not as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `jade` to a newer version -- to at least [`0.16.0`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/History.md#0160--2011-09-26-) for [template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11) with `block` and `extends`.

The current version is [`0.27.7`](https://npmjs.org/package/jade).

---

You may also want to update `express`, which is no longer an `rc` at [`3.0.4`](https://npmjs.org/package/express).

Comment: Thanks, I have updated Jade and Express and it is now working as expected. Thanks again for the help Jonathan.